# How to add default Spinner Icon in ag-grid cell and replace that with cell value

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have a requirement where I need to do async call and load value in each cell of one particular column and refresh the row once the value is available from the server. I want to have a loading spinner in the cell when grid got initialized and once the value for that particular row is available I need to replace the loading spinner icon with new value from the server. Right now I am using `cellRenderer` for passing data because I need to show the data in `<span class="badge badge-link">`.

Let me know if anyone has a good solution for this.

Comment: Do you load data for all rows for the column with one call? Or is it a separate call for each row in the column?

Comment: Its is separate call for each row. I am loading the data but for just one column I am making separate call and refreshing row after each call back to update that particular cell value.